# Looking for "clever" way of creating submatrices in matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, submatrix

I have a 2900 x 7 size matrix

```
re2 = [x y z se index xc yc];
```

Each column (x, y, z, se, index, xc, yc) contains numbers, all 2900 x 1 same size.

I am trying to make some submatrices from this one, by finding specific elements in 6th & 7th columns. Like this:

```
rexy_1_1 = re2(xc==1 & yc==1,:);
rexy_1_2 = re2(xc==1 & yc==2,:);
rexy_1_3 = re2(xc==1 & yc==3,:);
rexy_1_4 = re2(xc==1 & yc==4,:);
rexy_1_5 = re2(xc==1 & yc==5,:);
....
rexy_20_17 = re2(xc==20 & yc==17,:);
```

But this means I need to write 340 lines to generate 340 submatrices. Is there any clever way to do this? I tried to use two for-loops:

```
for i=1:20
    for j=1:17
        rexy_i_j = re2(xc==i & yc==j,:);
    end
end
```

But it did not work.

How can I get these submatrices?

Comment: Ouch! You cannot produce a new variable `rexy_i_j` each time (_i.e._ `rexy_1_1, `rexy_1_2`` simply by assignment. This just overruns the old value of the variable literally named `rexy_i_j`. I would suggest using cell arrays instead: `rexy{i, j}`. Also, do you have actual variables named `xc` and `yc`? I think you're not extracting the sub-matrices correctly...

Comment: Thanks, xc and yc are 2700 x 1 columns, contains numbers. xc contains nunmbers range from 1 to 20, yc contains 1 to 17.

Answer (score 4):

I concur with @EitanT that you should use cell arrays rather than make lots and lots of differently named arrays. You'd then be able to access these sub-matrices as `rexy{i,j}`.

To construct this cell array, you can use `accumarray` as follows:

```
rexy = accumarray(re2(:,6:7),(1:size(re2,1))',[],@(x){re2(x,:)})
```

Comment: That is crafty - I haven't seen accumarray used like that before. If you don't need to retain xc and yc after creating the cell arrays, you could change the last argument to re2(x,1:5) too.